# Linux terminal installation yes/no error

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to set up something, example: phpmyadmin;

Terminal CODE:

```
sudo  apt-get  install  phpmyadmin
```

When I enter this code a yes or no question is seen. I answer 'yes' 'y' but it is cancelled.

Comment: which linux distro are you using ?

Comment: linux mint 1.7 rebecca mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks you:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
                          ↑
```

Note the capital "Y", which means it's selected by default, so pressing "enter" is enough, no need to enter "yes".

Comment: yes i asked it . but  if i press only enter ; same error still  seems. but i can overcome with -aptitude install phpmyadmin -